What font is being used in Copilot answers?
I was using Copilot to get answers for my question. The font grabbed my attention:

The font was new to me. I had not seen a font with cross-shaped ts before (also, the top of the letter is a little slanted)
So, I tried to identify it using this website. I gave the picture to the website and it asked me to choose at least 8 characters so that they identify the font for me.
Only the 14th result seemingly matched my text (Olyford Medium otf):

But I'm not still satisfied if this is the exact font used in Copilot.
I also searched the net for Copilot font but found nothing. And also I searched the net for fonts with cross-shaped ts but none of them matched.
So, now I'm asking my question here so that a human can help me to identify this font.

Do you know that you can inspect a font on a web page using your browser?

@BillyKerr How can I do that?

@BillyKerr Of course, I use Copilot app. It doesn't run on browser.

You can use Copilot in a browser though, can't you?  So, you can just inpect it using Option 2 shown here

@BillyKerr Thanks. Does that option also work for non-English fonts like Persian and Chinese?

I can't speak or read Persian or Chinese, but I should imagine so. You're inspecting the code on the actual web page, and fonts are specified in the code.

font-family: Ginto,ui-sans-serif,system-ui,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji",Segoe UI Symbol,"Noto Color Emoji";

There's another useful tool here called Fount. It's even easier to use on a web page. It inspects the actual rendered font itself, and not just the code in the font stack.

For me, using Win 11 with Firefox the font Microsoft uses on the Copilot site is Ginto.

@BillyKerr Is the font used in Copilot on Firefox the same with the android app?

Yes. It looks exactly the same. see example using Fount to ID the font

@BillyKerr Thanks. So the question is solved. But I'm wondering why my question got a downvote! I have put my research (all I could) in it.

@BillyKerr Ginto looks like Olyford Medium otf very much though!

I'm sorry I don't know who downvoted your answer, it wasn't me. But it's probably because you didn't inspect it in your browser. But if you didn't know about that, then it's not very fair.  Welcome to GDSE anyway.  Yes it does look very similar to Olyford, but Ginto is the actual font used, no question. It's in the code, so you can be absolutely sure.

Ginto (primary)
ui-sans-serif (a system sans-serif font)
system-ui (another system font that adapts to the platform)
sans-serif (general sans-serif fallback)
Apple Color Emoji (for Apple devices)
Segoe UI Emoji (for Windows)
Segoe UI Symbol (Windows symbol font)
Noto Color Emoji (a Google font for emojis)
